# How to check the uniqueness of an ODE ,when the function in the R.H.S of the ODE is not Locally lipschitz

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $$\dot X=f(X)$$ $$X(0)=X_0$$ be an ODE. If  $f$ is locally Lipschitz, then the uniqueness of the solution of the  ODE is guaranteed. How to check the uniqueness if $f$ is not Locally Lipschitz? For example if $X\in \mathbb R$ and $f(X)=3X^{(\frac{2}{3})}$ and $X_0=0$ then the two solutions of the ODE is $$X(t)=t^3$$ and$$X(0)=0$$ but if we replace the initial condition by $X_0=1$then it seems to me the only solution is $$X(t)=(t+1)^3$$ Now how to check wheather there are others solution or not?

Comment: When you consider $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)\times (1-\delta, 1+\delta)$ then $f(X) = 3X^{2/3}$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: There are more solutions, in fact uncountably many. Indeed, for $a>1$ the function $X(t)=(t+a)^3$ for $t\in(-\infty,-a)$, $X(t)=0$ for $t\in[-a,-1]$ and $X(t)=(t+1)^3$ for $t\in(-1,\infty)$ satisfies the IVP. Further, $X(t)=0$ for $t\in(-\infty,-1]$, $X(t)=(t+1)^3$ satisfies the IVP, too.

Comment: Now is there any guarantee that if f is not locally Lipschitz, then there exists more than one solution of the IVP?